# Facebook not pulling meta data from blog

Tags: html, css, facebook, metadata

I've noticed that my blog posts (  ) starting from November 12 on wards have not been pulling up the metadata at all when posting to Facebook. I checked my previous posts from before November 12, and everything seems to be okay. Not sure what's wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

I've placed a link to a couple of screen shots below...

Non-working meta data pull:

Working meta data pull:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Facebook Object Debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) is [reporting a problem with your og:image](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fnubaseagency.com%2Fnews%2F13606757):

> Unable to download og:image:  The image referenced by the url of
>   og:image tag could not be downloaded.

Looking at the source of your site, I don't see an [`og:image`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/) tag at all.

Comment: Steve, how can i go about fixing this issue? http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nubaseagency.com%2Fnews

Comment: @jbnbtw just add the `og:image` meta tag to your html: `<meta property="og:image" content="http://nubaseagency.com/path/to/image.jpg"/>`